# What would be the most efficient way of inputting integers and getting the letters that form the word?

Tags: java, algorithm

I mean receive as an input for example: 3 and as output t,h,r,e. I was thinking about using an array but I'd have to store all numbers from 0 to 20 then by the thenths (30,40,etc) until 100 is there a better way?

I'm working in Java, and still have no code I'm in the design phase at the moment.

Comment: For what range of integers are you trying to do this?

Comment: is this homework? If so, please honestly mark it as such using the tag system.

Comment: nope it's not. I am doing some coding challenges to practice for my next interview =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map.

```
public class NumberToWord {

    private Map<Integer, String> map;

    public NumberToWord() {
        map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        // populate all the strings for 0 - 20
        // and 30, 40, ..., 100
        map.put(0, "z,e,r,o");
        map.put(1, "o,n,e");
        map.put(2, "t,w,o");
        map.put(3, "t,h,r,e,e");
        map.put(4, "f,o,u,r");
        map.put(5, "f,i,v,e");
        map.put(6, "s,i,x");
        map.put(7, "s,e,v,e,n");
        map.put(8, "e,i,g,h,t");
        map.put(9, "n,i,n,e");
        map.put(10, "t,e,n");
        map.put(11, "e,l,e,v,e,n");
        map.put(12, "t,w,e,l,v,e");
        map.put(13, "t,h,i,r,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(14, "f,o,u,r,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(15, "f,i,f,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(16, "s,i,x,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(17, "s,e,v,e,n,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(18, "e,i,g,h,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(19, "n,i,n,e,t,e,e,n");
        map.put(20, "t,w,e,n,t,y");
        map.put(30, "t,h,i,r,t,y");
        map.put(40, "f,o,r,t,y");
        map.put(50, "f,i,f,t,y");
        map.put(60, "s,i,x,t,y");
        map.put(70, "s,e,v,e,n,t,y");
        map.put(80, "e,i,g,h,t,y");
        map.put(90, "n,i,n,e,t,y");
        map.put(100, "h,u,n,d,,r,e,d");    
    }

    public String toWord(int number) {
        if(number < 0 || number > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number should 0 to 100");
        }
        if(number == 100 || number < 21) { //if the number is 100 or less than 21
            return map.get(number); //just lookup and return
        } else {                      //otherwise 
            int dig = number % 10;    
            String r = map.get(dig);  //lookup for the last digit 
            dig = (number / 10) * 10; //and for the tens
            r = map.get(dig) + "," + r; // and combine
            return r;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        NumberToWord ntw = new NumberToWord();
        System.out.println(0 + ": " + ntw.toWord(0));
        System.out.println(1 + ": " + ntw.toWord(1));
        System.out.println(11 + ": " + ntw.toWord(11));
        System.out.println(20 + ": " + ntw.toWord(20));
        System.out.println(29 + ": " + ntw.toWord(29));
        System.out.println(99 + ": " + ntw.toWord(99));
        System.out.println(100 + ": " + ntw.toWord(100));
        System.out.println(75 + ": " + ntw.toWord(75));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: z,e,r,o
1: o,n,e
11: e,l,e,v,e,n
20: t,w,e,n,t,y
29: t,w,e,n,t,y,n,i,n,e
99: n,i,n,e,t,y,n,i,n,e
100: h,u,n,d,,r,e,d
75: s,e,v,e,n,t,y,f,i,v,e
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to map integers to the English words for those numbers. If that is the case, then there really isn't an easier way than the one you've started to sketch out. Your code will need to store the words for all integers for which there isn't a rule and capture all the rules for the rest.

For example: for 0-19, you'll need to store the corresponding word. For 20, 30, ..., 90, you will need to store those words. For the rest of the numbers between 0 and 99, you can write a rule. A rules for 100, 200, ..., 900 is a little bit easier, since you just need to put the corresponding unit word in front of "hundred". And so on.

Comment: yes that's precisely what I want to do, so the way I'm thinking of it is a good one then.